# React hook page throws 'filter' of undefined (anonymous) exception and unable to perform search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have implemented a `React hook`home page where I have got list of players displaying, I have added an `input search` to search the players based on the `player name or Position`, but it throws below exception,could someone please advise the cause of exception;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined (anonymous
>   function) C:/Project1/soccerpep/src/components/Home.js:18   15 |
>   setSearchTerm(event.target.value);   16 | };   17 | React.useEffect(()
>   => {
>
> > 18 | const results = playerList.name.filter(player =>
> >          | ^  19 |     player.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)   20 | );   21 | setSearchResults(results);

The react hook page follows below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

var playerList = [
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 1', position: "Forward" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 2', position: "Defense" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 3', position: "Mid Fielder" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 4', position: "Forward" }
];
const Home = () => {

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
 useEffect(() => {
  const results = playerList.name.filter(player =>
      player.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );
  setSearchResults(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="playerList_header">
          <h1>Players</h1> 
            <label>
              <div className="playerSearch_Home">
                <div className="playerSearch_Icon">
                  <img src="/images/search-image-player.jpg"></img>
                </div>
              <input type="text" className="playerSearch_Home_Input" placeholder="Search players..." value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange}/>
              </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div className="playerList_home_page">
          <div className="grid-container">
            {
              playerList.map(player => {
                return (
                  <div className="grid-item">
                    <div>
                      <img className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" key={player.image} src={player.image}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="playerProfile_grid_border">
                      <h3 key={player.name}>{player.name}</h3>
                      <span className="playerPosition_home_tile" key={player.position}>{player.position}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
            },
              {
              searchResults.map(player => {
              return (
                <div className="grid-item">
                    <div>
                      <img className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" key={player.image} src={player.image}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="playerProfile_grid_border">
                      <h3 key={player.name}>{player.name}</h3>
                      <span className="playerPosition_home_tile" key={player.position}>{player.position}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              );
          })
        }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playerList` is an array, not an object, it doesn't have property `name`:

```
const results = playerList.filter(player =>
      player.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || player.position.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and I have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can be used only on arrays, you tried to run on `name` property which does not exist.

Instead you can use as the following:

```js
var playerList = [
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 1', position: "Forward" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 2', position: "Defense" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 3', position: "Mid Fielder" },
  { image: '/images/person.png', name: 'Player 4', position: "Forward" }
];

const searchTerm = 'Player 2';

const results = playerList.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLowerCase());
  
console.log(results);
```

I hope this explains!

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Just extended, thanks for mentioning!